# Is a C++ template able to "forward any class function" from parent class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, forwarding

```
class Foo {
public:
  void methodA();
};

class ManagedFoo {
Foo fooInst;
public:
  void methodA() { doSomething(); fooInst.methodA();}
};
```

Now I want to make ManagedFoo as a template, managing any class not only Foo, and before any of Foo's function is called, call doSomething first.

```
template<typename _TyManaged>
class Manager {
  _TyManaged _managedInst;
  void doSomething();
public:
  /*Forward every function called by _managedInst*/
  /*How to write this?*/
};
```

I want to make it the same, make it replaceable between this two class, like this :

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
foo->methodA();

Manager<Foo> managedFoo = new Manager<Foo>();
managedFoo->methodA(); //Hope it call Manager::doSomething() first then call _managedInst.methodA();
```

Can C++11 template do such thing? if answer is yes, how to?

Comment: Just to understand what you want, why not just use fooInst itself? Should this be a delegate?

Comment: Look at how the operator  `->` is implemented for `std::shared_ptr`, this may be close enough.

Comment: Sorry I should have made myself more clear, I've updated the question, thanks all~

Comment: I think you should get even more specific. I still can't see any use case for this feature you are asking for...

Comment: Nitpick: 17.6.4.3.2 [global.names]/1 "Each name that contains a double underscore `__` or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use." This means that the name `_TyManaged` is reserved for the compiler/library vendor and your code is illegal. However, chances that anything wrong actually happens because of this are virtually zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution based on operator-> overloading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo\n"; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "bar\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
class ManagedBase {
    std::shared_ptr<T> _inst;
public:
    ManagedBase(const std::shared_ptr<T> inst) : _inst(inst) { }
    virtual ~ManagedBase() { }

    std::shared_ptr<T> operator->() {
        before();
        return this->_inst;
    }

    virtual void before() =0;
};


template <typename T>
class ManagedPrint : public ManagedBase<T> {
public:
    ManagedPrint(const std::shared_ptr<T> inst) : ManagedBase(inst) { }

    virtual void before() {
        std::cout << "Said: ";
    }
};


int main() {
    auto ma = ManagedPrint<A>(std::make_shared<A>());
    ma->bar();      // Said: foo
    ma->bar();      // Said: bar
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems great to override operator->! I will have a try~

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
template<typename _TyManaged>
class Manager {
  _TyManaged _managedInst;
  void doSomething();
public:
  _TyManaged* operator->() {
    doSomething();
    return &_managedInst;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding the light! It seems useful and I will have a try, thanks!

Comment: Take a look at @AlexanderMihailov solution too, it is similar but have better way of extending it.

Comment: Seems, posted these two answers simultaneously :) Another unsolved issue is how to call something *after* managed method call. Is it possible to make it easy?

Answer (score 2):

This can solve your problem. But I'm still not sure what you want to do with your Manager class.

```
class Foo {
  public:
    void methodA();
};

template<typename T>
class ManagedFoo : public T {
  public:
    // some further extensions
};
```

And of course in this way you change the semantic of the Foo class by the manager from: 
It has a
to
It is a
So I'm not sure if this is true in your case.

Comment: Sorry I was not make myself clear, I have updated the question, but thank you anyway :)